# /proc/stat - is guest counted into user time?

Tags: linux, cpu, proc

I have a quick question. In man page for /proc/stat this is not clear to me:
Is guest and guest_nice time included in user time in /proc/stat?

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html
in manual there is only a hint about /proc/[pid]/stat

https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/6/23/65
here, as far as I understand they are talking about both /proc/stat and /proc/[pid]/stat

Can someone explain it? And hopefully point to any source of this information?

Comment: The manpage makes it clear that the user time includes guest time in the section on `/proc/[pid]/stat`.

Answer (score 6):

From the man page:

```
This includes guest time,
guest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see
below), so that applications that are not aware of
the guest time field do not lose that time from
their calculations.
```

From the kernel source ([`.../kernel/sched/cputime.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/kernel/sched/cputime.c)) we see that when guest time is being accounted for, all guest time is also added to user time (and similarly for nice).

```
/*                                                                                
 * Account guest cpu time to a process.                                           
 * @p: the process that the cpu time gets accounted to                            
 * @cputime: the cpu time spent in virtual machine since the last update          
 * @cputime_scaled: cputime scaled by cpu frequency                               
 */
static void account_guest_time(struct task_struct *p, cputime_t cputime,
                               cputime_t cputime_scaled)
{
        u64 *cpustat = kcpustat_this_cpu->cpustat;

        /* Add guest time to process. */
        p->utime += cputime;
        p->utimescaled += cputime_scaled;
        account_group_user_time(p, cputime);
        p->gtime += cputime;

        /* Add guest time to cpustat. */
        if (task_nice(p) > 0) {
                cpustat[CPUTIME_NICE] += (__force u64) cputime;
                cpustat[CPUTIME_GUEST_NICE] += (__force u64) cputime;
        } else {
                cpustat[CPUTIME_USER] += (__force u64) cputime;
                cpustat[CPUTIME_GUEST] += (__force u64) cputime;
        }
}
```

The user time and guest time that will be displayed via `/proc/[pid]/stat` are retrieved in [`.../fs/proc/array.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/proc/array.c) in `do_task_stat()` with calls to `task_cputime_adjusted()` and `task_gtime()` which return the `utime` and `gtime` fields of `struct task_struct`, respectively, although gtime may be tweaked:

```
cputime_t task_gtime(struct task_struct *t)
{
        unsigned int seq;
        cputime_t gtime;

        if (!vtime_accounting_enabled())
                return t->gtime;

        do {
                seq = read_seqcount_begin(&t->vtime_seqcount);

                gtime = t->gtime;
                if (t->vtime_snap_whence == VTIME_SYS && t->flags & PF_VCPU)
                        gtime += vtime_delta(t);

        } while (read_seqcount_retry(&t->vtime_seqcount, seq));

        return gtime;
}
```

[code quoted in this post is from commit `29b4817 2016-08-07 Linus Torvalds Linux 4.8-rc1`]